# Finding min/max of quadratic bezier with CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, bezier

I am using CoreGraphics to draw a quadratic bezier but want to computer the min/max value of the curve.  I am not from a mathematical background so this has become a bit troublesome.  Does anyone have any articles or ideas about how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a quadratic Bezier, this is actually quite simple.

Define your three control points as `P0 = (x0,y0)`, `P1 = (x1,y1)` and `P2 = (x2,y2)`. To find the extrema in `x`, solve this equation:

```
t = (x0 - x1) / (x0 - 2*x1 + x2)
```

If `0 <= t <= 1`, then evaluate your curve at `t` and store the location as `Px`. Do the same thing for `y`:

```
t = (y0 - y1) / (y0 - 2*y1 + y2)
```

Again, if `0 <= t <= 1`, evaluate your curve at `t` and store the location as `Py`. Finally, find the axis-aligned bounding box containing `P0`, `P2`, `Px` (if found) and `Py` (if found). This bounding box will also tightly bound your 2D quadratic Bezier curve.

Comment: Thanks kangax. Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Calculus gives the standard box of tricks for finding the min/max of continuous, differentiable curves.

Here is a [sample discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20100220015754/http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.graphics.algorithms/2005-07/msg00334.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have made a representation of this in javascript:

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/CC5un/6/embedded/result/)

```
function P(x,y){this.x = x;this.y = y; }
function pointOnCurve(P1,P2,P3,t){
    if(t<=0 || 1<=t || isNaN(t))return false;
    var c1 =  new P(P1.x+(P2.x-P1.x)*t,P1.y+(P2.y-P1.y)*t);
    var c2 =  new P(P2.x+(P3.x-P2.x)*t,P2.y+(P3.y-P2.y)*t);
    return new P(c1.x+(c2.x-c1.x)*t,c1.y+(c2.y-c1.y)*t);  
}
function getQCurveBounds(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy){
    var  P1 = new P(ax,ay);
    var  P2 = new P(bx,by);
    var  P3 = new P(cx,cy);
    var tx =  (P1.x - P2.x) / (P1.x - 2*P2.x + P3.x);
    var ty =  (P1.y - P2.y) / (P1.y - 2*P2.y + P3.y);
    var Ex = pointOnCurve(P1,P2,P3,tx);
    var xMin = Ex?Math.min(P1.x,P3.x,Ex.x):Math.min(P1.x,P3.x);
    var xMax = Ex?Math.max(P1.x,P3.x,Ex.x):Math.max(P1.x,P3.x);
    var Ey = pointOnCurve(P1,P2,P3,ty);
    var yMin = Ey?Math.min(P1.y,P3.y,Ey.y):Math.min(P1.y,P3.y);
    var yMax = Ey?Math.max(P1.y,P3.y,Ey.y):Math.max(P1.y,P3.y);
    return {x:xMin, y:yMin, width:xMax-xMin, height:yMax-yMin};
}
```