# Resize UIView so that whatever I draw is visible - ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I have a `UIView`. I am drawing a line inside the `UIView` programmativally. But when the line goes outside the `UIView`, the part of the line which goes out, is invisible. How can I resize the `UIView` so that whatever I draw inside the `drawRect` method is visible?

Answer (score 1):

you can change the frame of view. If your line is horizontal then give width to view else increase height of view.

```
  view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origine.x, view.frame.origine.y,view.frame.size.width,lengthOfLine );
```

Comment: What I am drawing programmatically is actually a curve. And the middle part of the curve is what goes out.

Comment: then use some maths formula to calculate height or width

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a predefined way to do it. That's y i came here. But thank you for trying to helpl. It's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the curve you are drawing is a subview, then you can make use of `sizeToFit` method. This will make the view's frame enclose the curve(and all subviews, for that matter). Then you can reposition and scale the view's frame to make it fit in the window.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned in a comment that you are actually drawing a curve. From what I can tell, you will need to calculate the curve's bounding box yourself.

Based on the bounding box, update the `UIView`'s `bounds` property (as Durgaprasad [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16789384/39974)). This also resizes the underlying `CALayer`, which also gives its underlying Core Graphics rendering context a larger bitmap.

Without knowing more about your curve, it's hard to help, apart from [linking to some very generic discussion on quadratic Beziers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099291/39974).

You may want to update your question with a minimal implementation of `-drawRect:` that will allow someone to reproduce your issue.